# Reading lines and write them in another format in python

Tags: python, format, lines

I have  a file with this format:

```
    ELEM MAT TYP REL ESY SEC        NODES
       1   1   1   1   0   1      611    2856     618    2582   94075   94107   94065   94068
                               101071   94104
       2   1   1   1   0   1      598    2856     618     611   93995   94107   93992   93991
                                94075   94065

    ELEM MAT TYP REL ESY SEC        NODES

   37561  29  29   1   0  29    32186   32642   32666   32210   32187   32643   32667   32211
                               191297  192707  191370  191296  191300  192710  191373  191299
                               191295  192706  192779  191368
   37562  29  29   1   0  29    32187   32643   32667   32211   32188   32644   32668   32212
                               191300  192710  191373  191299  191303  192713  191376  191302
                               191298  192709  192782  191371
   37563  29  29   1   0  29    32188   32644   32668   32212   32189   32645   32669   32213
                               191303  192713  191376  191302  191305  192715  191378  191304
                               191301  192712  192785  191374
```

And what I need to have is this:

```
       1   1   1   1   0   1      611    2856     618    2582   94075   94107   94065   94068   101071   94104
       2   1   1   1   0   1      598    2856     618     611   93995   94107   93992   93991   94075   94065
   37561  29  29   1   0  29    32186   32642   32666   32210   32187   32643   32667   32211   191297  192707  191370  191296  191300  192710  191373  191299   191295  192706  192779  191368
   37562  29  29   1   0  29    32187   32643   32667   32211   32188   32644   32668   32212   191300  192710  191373  191299  191303  192713  191376  191302   191298  192709  192782  191371
   37563  29  29   1   0  29    32188   32644   32668   32212   32189   32645   32669   32213   191303  192713  191376  191302  191305  192715  191378  191304   191301  192712  192785  191374
```

I need the text to be deleted and the rest information to be written in on line. The text can be deleted also by postprocessing with excel. The big issue is to write the data in lines but some data are written in two and some other in three lines. The files contains element numbers and node numbers of a finite lement model. I need the nodes written after every element. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First try some solution/coding solution yourself and if you run into a problem with your code, then you are welcome to ask. Read this link, it will help with asking better questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

with open('untitled.txt') as f:
    # untitled.txt contains the input text.
    last_line = []
    for line in f:
        m = re.match('ELEM', line)
        if m:
            # if line has header, ignore and continue
            continue
        current_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
        m = re.match('^\s{20,30}', line)
        if m:
            # if line starts with a lot of spaces add values to previous line
            last_line.extend(current_numbers)
        else:
            if last_line:
                # if we have a previous line print it/ write it to file.
                print(last_line)
            # assign new line found as last line and continue with the loop
            last_line = current_numbers

if last_line:
    print(last_line)
```

output:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '611', '2856', '618', '2582', '94075', '94107', '94065', '94068', '101071', '94104']
['2', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '598', '2856', '618', '611', '93995', '94107', '93992', '93991', '94075', '94065']
['37561', '29', '29', '1', '0', '29', '32186', '32642', '32666', '32210', '32187', '32643', '32667', '32211', '191297', '192707', '191370', '191296', '191300', '192710', '191373', '191299', '191295', '192706', '192779', '191368']
['37562', '29', '29', '1', '0', '29', '32187', '32643', '32667', '32211', '32188', '32644', '32668', '32212', '191300', '192710', '191373', '191299', '191303', '192713', '191376', '191302', '191298', '192709', '192782', '191371']
['37563', '29', '29', '1', '0', '29', '32188', '32644', '32668', '32212', '32189', '32645', '32669', '32213', '191303', '192713', '191376', '191302', '191305', '192715', '191378', '191304', '191301', '192712', '192785', '191374']
```

PS: you can chose any formatting for writing it, which is up to you.

Comment: This is far away better than the one that I have tried to write. Thank you for teaching me!

Answer (score 0):

First, the basics:

```
data_out=open(filename,"r")
data_in=open(filename+"_output.txt","w")

for line in data_out:
    written=False
    if [...]
```

Than you could choose a sequence to make the code recognize, if its a "core line" (like 1   1   1   1   0   1      611    2856     618    2582   94075   94107   94065   94068) or a line which is just following ( 94075   94065). You can check it for example via the parameters REL/ESY wich seem to be boolean-ish. The hungover lines do not contain something like this. If a line contains " 0 " or " 1 " you can save it as a variable. Than append the following lines as long there is no new core line.

Print it into the new document

```
data_in.write(line)
```

Dont forget

```
data_in.close()
data_out.close()
```